# How to fix this elements?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Getting an error with some elements

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

#Import our historical data
data = pd.read_csv('Data/sample.csv')
data.columns = [['Date','open','high','low','close','vol']]
data = data.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
data.Date = pd.to_datetime(data.Date,format='%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
data = data.set_index(data.Date)
data = data[['open', 'high', 'close', 'vol']]

price = data.close.iloc[:100]

# Find our relative extrema
max_idx = argrelextrema(price.values,np.greater,order=1)
min_idx = argrelextrema(price.values,np.less,order=1)

print(max_idx)
print(min_idx)
```

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 9, in <module>
    data.columns = [['Date','open','high','low','close','vol']]

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass a list, not a list of list or pandas will interpret the nested list as one column name.

```py
data.columns = ['Date','open','high','low','close','vol']
```

## Edit 1

Your CSV file seems to be separated by `\t` :

```py
data = pd.read_csv('Data/sample.csv', sep=r'\t')
data.columns = ['Date','open','high','low','close','vol']
```

Comment: Same error: ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 6 elements

Comment: Could you please show an input of `data.head()` ? I'm pretty sure that your delimiter is wrong.

Comment: Sure, but Im not sure where to place data.head()?

Comment: just after `data = pd.read_csv('Data/sample.csv')` put `print(data.head())`and comment everything else. Then run your code and report here what you have.

Comment: Date\topen\thigh\tlow\tclose\tvol
0  2018.09.28 00:00:00\t1.16407\t1.16414\t1.1639\...
1  2018.09.28 00:15:00\t1.16409\t1.16414\t1.16388...
2  2018.09.28 00:30:00\t1.164\t1.16405\t1.16384\t...
3  2018.09.28 00:45:00\t1.16386\t1.16395\t1.16378...
4  2018.09.28 01:00:00\t1.16383\t1.16405\t1.16346...

Comment: @uname123 Did it work ? If yes feel free to validate my awnser by checking on the check mark under the up/down vote button.